# Spring Data JPA / Database config with ManyToOne/OneToMany/OneToOne without full objs in JSON

Tags: database-design, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, lombok, many-to-one

I have been really struggling with implementing my db setup for a boat rental site.
It used to just be **Order** with @OneToOne **Customer** and @OneToMany **Boats**. Nothing was nullable and everything worked, but I would POST and GET the entire **Order** for every query.

Now, I want to:

1. add custom tours (**TourObj**) with tour data
2. add **TourInstance**s with the specific dates and times.
3. I also want to be able to query by **TourInstance** and see the **Boat**s reserved for that day, and the **Customer** name.

---

**The problem**

Is that @ManyToOne etc is looking for the entire object in each request which is causing some concurrency issues and/or creating some super complex JSON being sent back and forth. I feel like this could be solved with just storing the IDs but then it would be manual instead of utilizing primary/foreign key relationships and thus prone to lots of errors...

---

**Question**

What is the best way to design my Spring Data JPA Entities to get these results? (Note, I am also using Project Lombok)

---

**Order**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Builder
@Data
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int order_id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JsonManagedReference("b")
    private List<Boat> boats;

}
```

**Customer**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@Builder
@Data
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

**Boat**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boat")
@Builder
@Data
public class Boat {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "boat")
    private String boat;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instance_id", referencedColumnName = "instance_id")
    @JsonBackReference("a")
    private TourInstance instance;

    @Column(name = "instance_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int instanceId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id")
    @JsonBackReference("b")
    private Order order;

    @Column(name = "order_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int orderId;

}
```

**TourObj**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tours")
@Builder
@Data
public class TourObj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tour_id")
    private int tourId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "tourType")
    private String tourType;  

    @Column(name = "pricePerPerson")
    private int pricePerPerson;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instanceId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("c")
    private List<TourInstance> instances = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**TourInstance**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tour_instances")
@Builder
@Data
public class TourInstance {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "instance_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int instanceId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tour_Id", referencedColumnName = "tour_id")
    @JsonBackReference("c")
    private TourObj tourObj;

    @Column(name = "tour_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private int tourId;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "time")
    private String time;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instance", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonManagedReference("a")
    private List<Boat> reservations;

}
```

---

Any thoughts on how I can better construct these Entities to achieve the results I am looking for?